# IMessage MSSticker view created from UIView incorrect sizing

Tags: swift, imessage-extension, mssticker, msstickerview

Hey I have been struggling with this for a couple of days now and can't seem to find any documentation out side of the standard grid views for `MSStickerView` sizes

I am working on an app that  creates `MSStickerViews` dynamically - it does this via converting a `UIView` into an `UIImage` saving this to disk then passing the URL to `MSSticker` before creating the `MSStickerView` the frame of this is then set to the size of the original view.

The problem I have is that when I drag the `MSStickerView` into the messages window, the `MSStickerView` shrinks while being dragged - then when dropped in the messages window, changes to a larger size. I have no idea how to control the size when dragged or the final image size

Heres my code to create an image from a view

```
extension UIView {
    func imageFromView() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, self.isOpaque, 0.0)
           defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
           if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
               self.layer.render(in: context)
               let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

               return image
           }
           return nil
       }
}
```

And here's the code to save this to disk

```
extension UIImage {
    func savedPath(name: String) -> URL{
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let filePath = "\(paths[0])/name.png"
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        // Save image.
        if let data = self.pngData() {
            do {
                try data.write(to: url)
            } catch let error as NSError {

            }
        }
        return url
    }
}
```

finally here is the  code that converts the data path to a Sticker

```
if let stickerImage = backgroundBox.imageFromView() {
        let url = stickerImage.savedPath(name: textBox.text ?? "StickerMCSticker")
        if let msSticker = try? MSSticker(contentsOfFileURL: url, localizedDescription: "") {

            var newFrame = self.backgroundBox.frame
            newFrame.size.width = newFrame.size.width
            newFrame.size.height = newFrame.size.height

            let stickerView = MSStickerView(frame: newFrame, sticker: msSticker)

            self.view.addSubview(stickerView)
            print("** sticker frame \(stickerView.frame)")
            self.sticker = stickerView
        }
    }
```

I wondered first off if there was something I need to do regarding retina sizes, but adding @2x in the file just breaks the image -  so am stuck on this - the WWDC sessions seem to show stickers being created from file paths and not altering in size in the transition between drag and drop - any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue eventually by getting the frame from the view I was copying's frame  then calling `sizeToFit()`-

```
  init(sticker: MSSticker, size: CGSize) {
        let stickerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        self.sticker = MSStickerView(frame: stickerFrame, sticker: sticker)
        self.sticker.sizeToFit()
        super.init(nibName: nil, bund
```

as the StickerView was not setting the correct size. Essentially the experience I was seeing was that the sticker size on my view was not accurate with the size of the MSSticker - so the moment the drag was initialized, the real sticker size was implemented (which was different to the frame size / autoLayout I was applying in my view)